# Declare in .h file? iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode

How would I declare this code in the header file (.h) in iPhone SDK?

```
- (void) save {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); 
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
- (void) save;
```

Comment: Would this be right? 

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface testViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> { 
 

}
- (void)save;

@end